# How to make this into for loop

Tags: jquery

I think it can make it into for loop but I am not sure how to express it? It can use me but how to express #form+i, whether it is #form[i] or #form{i}, i tried but it does not work.

Also, I want if the user does not select some answer, push "undefined" into an array to avoid it blank.

```
$('#form1').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer1']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form2').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer2']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form3').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer3']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form4').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer4']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form5').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer5']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form6').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer6']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});


$('#form7').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer7']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
$('#form8').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer8']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form9').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer9']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});

$('#form10').click(function() {
  radioValue = $("input[name='answer10']:checked");
  if (radioValue) {
    arr.push(radioValue.val())
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

Here is part of html.

```
  <div class="stepShow">
    <!--步驟區塊 -->
    <div class="stepArea stepAreaActive">
      <span><video style="width:300px" id="my_video" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/capstone-daa95.appspot.com/o/real%2Ffake%2F001_870.mp4?alt=media&token=96b7884c-9367-48b9-b422-0e6c238570db"></video></span>
      <form id="form1">
      <p>Choose whether this video is fake or real?
        <input name="answer1" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
        <input name="answer1" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
      </p>
    </form>

<!--       <a class="pre" onclick="preFun(0)" href="javascript:;">Contact</a>
 -->      <a class="next" onclick="nextFun(0)"  href="javascript:;">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepArea">
 <span><video style="width:300px" id="my_video" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/capstone-daa95.appspot.com/o/real%2Ffake%2F001_870.mp4?alt=media&token=96b7884c-9367-48b9-b422-0e6c238570db"></video></span>
 <form id="form2">
      <p>Choose whether this video is fake or real?
        <input name="answer2" type="radio" name="choice" value="real" > Real
        <input name="answer2" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake" > Fake
      </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML code?

Comment: Rather than a loop, you might [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it up by binding the same function to all elements. But yes, it would help to see your HTML.

Comment: As stated above, a `for` loop is the last thing you need here. This code needs DRYing up, but to show you the best way to do it we need the associated HTML.

Comment: The thing to do would be to give all the `<form` tags the same class, and then bind them to a single jquery event handler which selects all of them based on the class e.g. `$(".formlist").click`... (and all forms would be e.g. `<form class="formlist" id="`...etc). Obviously to get the correct radio button value the code would need to find that radio button by searching within the form (you can look up the jQuery `.find()` function to see how you could deal with that.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend binding the same handler function to all inputs.
This helps avoid repeating yourself (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and potentially facilitates more maintainable, flexible, and lightweight code.

Here's an example:

1. Bind a `change` event handler to all inputs.
2. When an input changes, iterate through all the steps and find their checked inputs.
3. For each step, add its checked value (or undefined) to the array.

```js
const $steps = $('.stepArea');
const $inputs = $('.inptAnswer');
const $output = $('#output');
let stepValues = [];

function getStepValues() {
  stepValues = $.map($steps, function(step) {
    return $('.inptAnswer:checked', step).val() || [undefined];
  });
  $output.text(stepValues);
}

$inputs.on('change', getStepValues);
```

```css
#output {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stepShow">

  <div class="stepArea stepAreaActive">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

---

Without jQuery, just for kicks:

```js
const steps = document.querySelectorAll('.stepArea');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inptAnswer');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
let stepValues = [];

function getStepValues() {
  stepValues = Array.from(steps).map((step) => {
    let input = step.querySelector('.inptAnswer:checked');
    return input ? input.value : undefined;
  });
  output.innerHTML = stepValues;
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', getStepValues);
});
```

```css
#output {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepShow">

  <div class="stepArea stepAreaActive">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="stepArea">
    <form class="form">
      Choose whether this video is fake or real?
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="real"> Real
      <input class="inptAnswer" type="radio" name="choice" value="fake"> Fake
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```